# impossible to resample date with python

Tags: python, date, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe called df1 :

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Desktop/equipement3.csv',delimiter=';', usecols = ['TIMESTAMP','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1'])
```

> TIMESTAMP;ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1
>
> 2015-07-31 23:00:00;90
>
> 2015-07-31 23:10:00;0
>
> 2015-07-31 23:20:00;0
>
> 2015-07-31 23:30:00;0
>
> 2015-07-31 23:40:00;0
>
> 2015-07-31 23:50:00;0
>
> 2015-08-01 00:00:00;0
>
> 2015-08-01 00:10:00;50
>
> 2015-08-01 00:20:00;0
>
> 2015-08-01 00:30:00;0
>
> 2015-08-01 00:40:00;0

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
style.use('ggplot')


df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['TIMESTAMP'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df1 = df1.drop('TIMESTAMP', axis=1)
df1 = d1f.resample('resamplestring', how='mean')
```

I got this kind of error :

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Could you help meplease?

Thank you

Comment: what is `resamplestring`? `df1 = d1f.resample('resamplestring', how='mean')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameter `parse_dates` and `index_col` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""TIMESTAMP;ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1

2015-07-31 23:00:00;90

2015-07-31 23:10:00;0

2015-07-31 23:20:00;0

2015-07-31 23:30:00;0

2015-07-31 23:40:00;0

2015-07-31 23:50:00;0

2015-08-01 00:00:00;0

2015-08-01 00:10:00;50

2015-08-01 00:20:00;0

2015-08-01 00:30:00;0

2015-08-01 00:40:00;0"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                  sep=";", 
                  usecols = ['TIMESTAMP','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1'], 
                  parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'],
                  index_col=['TIMESTAMP'] )
```

```
print (df1)
                     ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1
TIMESTAMP                                  
2015-07-31 23:00:00                      90
2015-07-31 23:10:00                       0
2015-07-31 23:20:00                       0
2015-07-31 23:30:00                       0
2015-07-31 23:40:00                       0
2015-07-31 23:50:00                       0
2015-08-01 00:00:00                       0
2015-08-01 00:10:00                      50
2015-08-01 00:20:00                       0
2015-08-01 00:30:00                       0
2015-08-01 00:40:00                       0

print (df1.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-31 23:00:00', '2015-07-31 23:10:00',
               '2015-07-31 23:20:00', '2015-07-31 23:30:00',
               '2015-07-31 23:40:00', '2015-07-31 23:50:00',
               '2015-08-01 00:00:00', '2015-08-01 00:10:00',
               '2015-08-01 00:20:00', '2015-08-01 00:30:00',
               '2015-08-01 00:40:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TIMESTAMP', freq=None)

#pandas 0.18.0 and more 
print (df1.resample('30Min').mean())
                     ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1
TIMESTAMP                                  
2015-07-31 23:00:00               30.000000
2015-07-31 23:30:00                0.000000
2015-08-01 00:00:00               16.666667
2015-08-01 00:30:00                0.000000
```

---

```
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
print (df1.resample('30Min', how='mean'))
TIMESTAMP                                  
2015-07-31 23:00:00               30.000000
2015-07-31 23:30:00                0.000000
2015-08-01 00:00:00               16.666667
2015-08-01 00:30:00                0.000000
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response.  In that case when I try to do  df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/equipement.csv', sep=";", 
                  usecols = ['TIMESTAMP','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1'], 
                  parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'],
                  index_col=['TIMESTAMP'])              I got an error : "ValueError: 'TIMESTAMP' is not in list"  . How can I fix it? Thank you in advance. Bests

Comment: Works for you my sample? If yes, what is version of your pandas?

Comment: Yes with your sample it works fine.  My panda''s version  : '0.18.1'

Comment: Is possible share your csv if not confidental?

Comment: No it is a toy csv file , so its not confidential. But How can I share ir, Im new here in SO?

Comment: You can use dropbox or wetransfer or google docs and then past link to comment.

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/cc518adb902d1be2b0ae319f3071694020160728065524/7e55edcfaf0d8d9b67041c81e19c16a620160728065524/a92873

Comment: In your example : TIMESTAMP and ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 are one aligned..maybe this is the cause of the problem

Comment: For me works add `r` to `filename` : `df1 = pd.read_csv(r'c:/Dropbox/work-joy/so/csv/equipement3.csv', 
                  sep=";", 
                  usecols = ['TIMESTAMP','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1'], 
                  parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'],
                  index_col=['TIMESTAMP'] )
print (df1)`

Comment: Ok thank you, but I thik that there is a problem :                     ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 and  TIMESTAMP are not aligned columns, So It seems impossible to do a plot for DF1 .

Comment: Are rows not aligned in csv?

Comment: They are aligned , it is the same file that I shared with you. I dont know why in the Data frame I see that they are not aligned :

Comment: look , even in your example that posted it yesterday, the column TIMESTAMP and  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 are not aligned

Comment: What does it mean not aligned? in csv are `6 times` zeros between `90` and `50` and in output `DataFrame` too. What is wrong?

Comment: I mean in the first line there is ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1   after in the second line there is  timestamp, after in the thirsd line I found the value

Comment: Maybe I have to do the question with another way : whey It is impossibble to plot df1 with your example? Is it possible for you to do a plot?

Comment: ploting is possible by `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df1.resample('M').mean().plot()
    plt.show()` if you need resample by `month`

Comment: Glad can help you. And if you want, you can upvote too my answer - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.